# VOIP devices unable to register with the providers

Tags: voip, softphone

My VOIP devices have been unable to register on their networks for at least the last 12 hours.  These devices were working fine before.

1. I have tried the Grandstream HT802 with 2 different providers.  One is using port 5060, the other 5061.
2. I have tried the Blink softphone with one provider.

There seemed to be an internet outage yesterday (my internet was not working for a period of at least several minutes).  Registering on the VOIP network did not work once web browsing starting working again.

So far, one provider wrote back to me saying that their servers are working.

Comment: Has your IP been changed to CGN?

Comment: @davidgo CGN right now.  (The WAN IP address in the router is different than the public IP address.)  I am not sure about before, never heard of the term until reading your post.

Comment: I contacted my ISP and they rebooted the modem and ran some tests.  They didn't find anything during the tests and tried to blame the problem on all kinds of illogical nonsense.  Towards the end of the call with them, the voip worked.  This is a mystery because I had unplugged the modem and plugged it back in (after waiting a long while) at least 2 times before contacting them.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you still behind CGN?